# how to image upload and crop and save in yii

Tags: yii, crop, jcrop, image-upload

i am trying to upload image in yii and then crop the uploaded image and then save it. what i have achieved till now is i can upload in on form submit but i dont understand to crop it or use `jcrop` for that can anyone send some usefull tutorials for that
what i am doing in my controller is

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Userprofile;
    if(isset($_POST['Userprofile']))
    {
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Userprofile'];
    $model->profilePic=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'profilePic');
    $ext = $model->profilePic->getExtensionName();
    $imagename=date('dmy').time().rand();
    $pp=$model->profilePic;
    $model->profilePic=$imagename.'.'.$ext;
    if($model->save())
        mkdir('profilepics/'.$model->id,0777);
        $pp->saveAs('profilepics/'.$model->id.'/'.$imagename.'.'.$ext);
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }
    $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,));
}
```

Comment: What are you looking for. Serverside cropping or clientside cropping ?

Comment: @dInGd0nG client side cropping and then uploaded to server cropped image

Comment: @Bipin,  you have to use flash component for crop image at clienside. Try this examples http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php

Comment: @Sergey now i got a different solution i will post it thanks for u r suggestion i will try it too.

Comment: Search the Yii wiki?

http://www.yiiframework.com/search/?q=image+uploader&type=wiki&lang=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery plugin imageAreaSelect to get coordinates for cropping at client-side. Here is live example http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/.

Then pass coordinates to model`s beforeSave and crop it using Imagick::cropImage() (instead of Imagick you can use GD or any other library you want)

Answer (score 0):

NavaJcrop extension is one of best solution to upload and crop image for me..Here is link of extension
[NavaJcrop Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nava-jcrop/)

Please follow it step